# Stylelint in PhpStorm as in vscode-stylelint

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, webstorm, lint, stylelint

My entire team uses VScode for development and uses the default settings for "vscode-stylelint" plugin. I use PhpStorm and there is also stylelint available but I need a configuration file for it to work as it should.

Is there some exportable ruleset available for "vscode-stylelint" plugin so that I can import it into PhpStorm?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest asking this at https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint/issues

Answer (score 0):

The Stylelint VS Code extension doesn't have a ruleset built-in. It reads the ruleset the [Stylelint configuration object](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure) in the project folder, e.g `.stylelintrc`. PHPSTorm should also read the same file automatically. If it doesn't, there's probably an option to point it at that file.